# Only allow 10 things in an array to be true

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public static bool[] chosen = new bool[27];

private void pictureBoxTopLeft3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        n = 18;
        cardSelect();
        highlightCards();
    } // There are many of these.

public static void cardSelect()
    {
        if (chosen[n] == false)
        {
            chosen[n] = true;
        }
        else if (chosen[n] == true)
        {
            chosen[n] = false;
        }
    }
```

There are multiple picture boxes. Once the picture box is clicked, in this example the picture box being "pictureBoxLeft3", it runs "cardSelect". This sets that picture box to true in the array "chosen". If clicked again, it is set to false.

There are 20 picture boxes in total. How can I make it so only 10 of those can be set to true at one time in the array "chosen". Thanks!

Comment: Comparisons with boolean values, such as `== false` and `== true`, are nonsense operations, remove them. `x == true` is the same as `x`. `x == false` is `!x`. Might as well write `((x == true) == true) == true` otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store state or calculate on the fly.

Storing state:

```
static int chosenCount = 0;

public static void cardSelect()
{
    if (chosen[n] == false)
    {
        if (chosenCount < 10)
        {
            chosen[n] = true;
            chosenCount++;
        }
        // else show a message maybe?
    }
    else if (chosen[n] == true)
    {
        chosen[n] = false;
        chosenCount--;
    }
}
```

Calculating:

```
using System.Linq;

public static void cardSelect()
{
    if (chosen[n] == false)
    {
         if (chosen.Count(c => c) < 10)
         {
            chosen[n] = true;
         }
    }
    else if (chosen[n] == true)
    {
        chosen[n] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was going to use the storing state version as I don't really know how the calculating version works, but for my project, I would need to save the value of "chosenCount" along with the selected pictures. I could do this by checking which pictures are set to true with a for loop and chosenCount++ every time i load the page but the System.Linq version was a lot easier. :D

Comment: What dont you understand about it? LINQ are some handy extension methods to run on IEnumerables like arrays and lists. .Count will count all the elements which match a condition.

In this circumstance, we just count the elements which are true (c => c) which is short hand for "c => c == true".

So .Count(c => c) is essentially this (sorry for poor formatting):
"int count;
 for (int i = 0; i < chosen.Length; i++)
{
   if (chosen[i] == true)
      count++;
}
return count;"

Comment: I'm fairly new to programming so I havn't come across .Count before. I don't get where the "c" comes from and what it is.

Comment: The c is arbitrary, it could be anything but a descriptive 1 letter is common (c meant "chosen"). .Count is part of LINQ, and the bit inside is a "predicate delegate" written as a lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a global variable `selectedCount` and whenever user selects a picture you increment `selectedCount` by 1. If `selectedCount` < 10 user can select more pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using linq

```
public static bool[] chosen = new bool[27];

public static void cardSelect()
    {

        if (chosen[n] == false && chosen.Count(a => a == true) < 10)
        {
            chosen[n] = true;
        }
        else if (chosen[n] == true)
        {
            chosen[n] = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That LINQ statement can be improved, .Count() can take a predicate so you don't need a .Where before it.